# solarized dark for vim and incorrect background color with xterm terminal emulator, black instead of darkblue

Tags: vim, color-scheme

Following is my configuration for solarized colorscheme.

`let g:solarized_termcolors=256
 set t_Co=256
 set background=dark
 colorscheme solarized`

But the background color is not dark blue, but dark or grey, similar like that.

I have tried remove `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`, remove `set t_Co=256`, add `let g:solarized_termcolors=16` or add `set t_Co=16`. But still display the wrong background color.

How can I do any config to change that incorrect background color to darkblue ?

Comment: Which terminal? And did you tried this:

http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized

`Again, I recommend just changing your terminal colors to Solarized values either manually or via one of the many terminal schemes available for import.`

Comment: Agreed with @AlexKroll. Check if there is support for your terminal here https://github.com/altercation/solarized#terminal-emulators and you need to make sure your terminal is in 256 colors mode

Comment: Thank u guys, I'm already solved this problem. The reason is the color of number `234` and `235` of 256 colors mode in my terminal emulator displayed grey. I changed the color of `base03` from `234` and `base02` from `235` to `NONE` in the script`solarized.vim` and changed the background color of my terminal emulator to darkblue. Then, bingo, I got what  I want.

Comment: @jas0ns can you tell where you changed the background color of terminal emulator to darkblue ? or try to answer your own question .

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay in that solarized vimscript file, for my environment, is ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasOns, to add to your solution to still allow the option to toggle between light and dark backgrounds, you can add the following *below* where `base02` and `base03` are set.

```
if &background == "dark"     
  let s:base03 = "NONE"     
  let s:base02 = "NONE"     
endif
```