# Getting Vim Solarized to work on iTerm

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme, iterm2

I've been using the solarized dark theme for a while now on iTerm, and it never quite looked like the original one. I decided to try and sort it out, and found all sorts of answers here and other sites:

- [Using the same theme](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) for iTerm itself.
- [Changing the `$TERM` value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201779/179502) (with and without `tmux`).
- [Changing misc `g:solarized_*` values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5561823/187907) (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized)).
- [Overriding some color defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962401/solarized-dark-for-vim-and-incorrect-background-color-with-xterm-terminal-emulat).

I also reduced my `.vimrc` to just loading the solarized theme to ensure no other plugin is messing up the colors.

Regardless, whatever I do I end up with this (terminal vim on left, MacVim on right):

[image: vim comparison]

The terminal background always appears black vs. the darkblue for solarized. This happens whether the actual terminal background color is black, white, etc.

My current terminal reports 256 color support and `TERM=xterm-256color`. The `t_Co` variable is also reporting `256`.

[image]

Would appreciate any insights on what I may have missed, as I've already spent *way* too much time on this. Thanks.

**Disclaimer**: *I realize this is a possible duplicate of many similar posts, but non resolved my issue.*

Comment: what about the theme of 'terminal' ? if you use https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/Solarized%20Dark%20ansi.terminal , it's the same as maciterm

Comment: Yeah, I ended up the similar as the right half of your 1st picture, and it's ugly!! How can it be that it's end of 2016 and 2017 is coming, and there is no authoritative guide on installing solarize on iTerm2....

Comment: So, can you clarify: 1. You don't want to use iTerm's DarkSolarized colors? 2. And, you want your background to be that solarized darkblue color in vim?

Comment: Have you tried installing the theme from this repo ? https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized (Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized')

Comment: also I set t_Co=256 permanently and not conditionally

Answer (score 0):

The official github repo for solarized is [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). I use this repo and never had problems so far. You have to import the colorscheme into iterm2 and thats it.

As a sidenote, do you mind to post relevant parts of your terminal and vim config? Maybe we overlooked something...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image of the terminal and the output of the `perl ~/Downloads/256colors2.pl` command, it appears you haven't properly set the colors for your terminal. Have you looked at the relevant iTerm files here? https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized?